# Publishing tfs work item entry application

Tags: asp.net, tfs, tfs-workitem

I developed a small program that contains a web form. in this form user fills fields of a Team Foundation Server work item and I add it to **TFS** work item tracker as a bug. It's all nice and well up to this point, but when I published this web application and hosted on `IIS 7` I came across the following exception:

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.Cache' or one of its
>   dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect
>   format.

Noting that I use `.net 4` and my team foundation assemblies' version is 10. besides I have `IIS 7` on my server.

Please give me a hand to fix this issue.

Comment: The server where you published the web app has TeamExplorer (VS2010 or TeamExplorer Standalone) installed? Is your application set up to use the correct ASP version?

Comment: checked. there wasn't any problem

Comment: There are several threads regarding this issue and it seems to be a problem between 32/64bit format. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643654/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-teamfoundation-workitemtracking-clien

Comment: Well, I did a comprehensive failed search on stackoverflow and other sources on the net before I posted this thread. by the way thank you Mike for your time. we've just found the solution. at first place I published this project with vs 2012 and all this problem arose. next I tried publishing exactly the same solution with vs 2010 and then there was no clues of any problem. sincerely I don't know why, we've just moved on...

Comment: Good to hear that. Usually the best approach is to use the equivalent versions of TFS and VS, otherwise you have to be carfeful. My guess is that you have developed the app on a machine where only VS2012 was installed and run it on a machine with VS2010/TeamExplorer2010, but in that case I would expect a "Could not load assembly" error.